# ZipArchive, I need to create new file and overwrite existing

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I am using php ZipArchive and I have run into a simple problem.

I need to create new file and if there is existing file with that name I need to overwrite it.

My problem is this, if I use this code

```
if ($zip->open($packageFileName, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) === TRUE)
```

it will overwrite any existing file with the same name, however if file with such a name does not exist then nothing happens, if case returns false and I fill the zip file with files inside this if case, but since if file is not on the disk above fails and no file gets created.

If I do this

```
if ($zip->open($packageFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
```

it will return true and file will be either created or updated, but I do not want to update the file, I need to overwrite the file.

So I am stuck a bit, I want file overwritten and if it does not exist I want it created, is there a way to do this in one line so I do not have to check this in multiple lines where I check if file exists and then pick either CREATE or OVERWRITE, why is there not CREATE_OVERWRITE Constant?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just like the error codes in PHP the zip flags are also bitwise additive means you can combine them using OR (`|`) to do more...

```
if ($zip->open($packageFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE))
```

Above will create a zip if it's not there else will overwrite. So this is how you do your `CREATE_OVERWRITE`.

Comment: In my application, I need to compress an uploaded file from browser.
I tried to use both CREATE and OVERWRITE in my code. However, when the file does not exist, it does not create the new archive file. Is this full proof? In my application there will be always one file in the archive. So I deleted the archive file if it existed, and used only CREATE. And as OVERWRITE ignores any existing files in the archive, it is not suitable in application where we give the user a downloadable file (after uncompressing it) which has only one file in the archive